# ASP Identity - The entity type IdentityRole is not part of the model for the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I extended the Identity Models, so that I can have an `Int` instead of a `string` regarding the users **Primary Key**.

```
namespace BeyondMembership.Models
{
    // You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your ApplicationUser class, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
    {
      ...
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, CustomRole,
        int, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {

        }

        static ApplicationDbContext()
        {
            // Set the database intializer which is run once during application start
            // This seeds the database with admin user credentials and admin role
            Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(new ApplicationDbInitializer());
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
}

public class CustomUserRole : IdentityUserRole<int> { }
public class CustomUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<int> { }
public class CustomUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<int> { }

public class CustomRole : IdentityRole<int, CustomUserRole>
{
    public CustomRole() { }
    public CustomRole(string name) { Name = name; }
}

public class CustomUserStore : UserStore<ApplicationUser, CustomRole, int,
    CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
{
    public CustomUserStore(ApplicationDbContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }
}

public class CustomRoleStore : RoleStore<CustomRole, int, CustomUserRole>
{
    public CustomRoleStore(ApplicationDbContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }
}
```

So I am getting an error on `roleManager.FindByName(roleName);`:

```
//Create User=Admin@Admin.com with password=Admin@123456 in the Admin role        
public static void InitializeIdentityForEF(ApplicationDbContext db)
{
    var userManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    var roleManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationRoleManager>();
    var role = roleManager.FindByName(roleName); // The entity type IdentityRole is not part of the model for the current context
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Are you sure you're configuring the correct context in your StartupAuth.cs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably missing some implementations. Take a look at this sample, it's already using an `Int` as Primary key, and doing what you need to do.

https://github.com/TypecastException/AspNet-Identity-2-With-Integer-Keys

Comment: I'm facing the same error, but I've simply added a new field in the Role entity. No way to get it working even following the code at the link you've posted.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47351526/asp-net-identity-2-0-custom-role-manager-the-entity-type-identityrole-is-not-pa

Answer (score 1):

Since you used CustomRole - you should apply all other places too, hope you get the point.

```
public class ApplicationRoleManager : RoleManager<CustomRole,int>
{
    public ApplicationRoleManager(IRoleStore<CustomRole,int> roleStore)
        : base(roleStore)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationRoleManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationRoleManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        //return new ApplicationRoleManager(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
        return new ApplicationRoleManager(new CustomRoleStore(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
    }
}
```